# ASP.NET controls positioning

Tags: html, asp.net

I haven't studied a lot about positioning of controls in ASP.NET using .Net framework 3.5 but still I know following control positioning technique isn't the best one, just to mention its a user control,

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Number of Days"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Right now I am using tabs and spaces to position controls but can I do it in a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use CSS and some HTML to put things where they belong. Theres is nothing special about ASP.NET controls just check the generated HTML markup on the client side.